# Why does Integrate get this wrong?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Why does `Integrate` get this wrong?

```
b = 2;

NIntegrate[E^(-x^2) HypergeometricU[-b/2, 1/2, x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
           AccuracyGoal -> 4]
(* -7.67473*10^-9 *)

Clear[b];

Integrate[E^(-x^2) HypergeometricU[-b/2, 1/2, x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* ConditionalExpression[-(((-2 + b) Sqrt[π] Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - b)/2, 1/2, 1])/
                           Gamma[1 - b/2]), Re[b] > 0] *)

f[b_] := ConditionalExpression[-(((-2 + b) Sqrt[π]
                                  Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - b)/2, 1/2, 1])/
                                 Gamma[1 - b/2]), Re[b] > 0]

f[2]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Comment: Have you submiited a bug report toWRI?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is unable to determine the limit f[b] for b->2.

If you don't integrate to Infinity, but only up to a cutoff c you get

```
c = 10; Table[{NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] HypergeometricU[-b/2, 1/2, x^2], {x, -c, c}],c MeijerG[{{1/2}, {(1 - b)/2}}, {{0, 1/2}, {-(1/2)}}, c^2]}, {b, 0,
3, 0.2}] // N
```

with good agreement.

Comment: Andreas, you are not right: `Limit[-(((-2 + b) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - b)/2, 1/2, 1])/Gamma[1 - b/2]), b -> 2, 
 Direction -> "FromAbove"]` performs `0` and `Limit[-(((-2 + b) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - b)/2, 1/2, 1])/Gamma[1 - b/2]), b -> 2, 
 Direction -> "FromBelow"]` produces  `ComplexInfinity`. I think the result of `Integrate` is not correct.

Comment: Because the results from above and below are different the value f[2] is returned as 'indeterminate'. With the cutoff in the integration range one gets an analytic result (MeijerG) with reasonable accuracy.

Comment: If you leave `c` symbolic and integrate, then take the (direction-free) limit as `b->2`, you get `c*Exp[-c^2]`. This of course vanishes as `c->Infinity`.

Comment: I found the answer in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 7th edition, formula 7.621.6.  You have to change variables to transform to their integral.  The answer to the Integrate[ ..] above is Sqrt[Pi]/Gamma[-b/2 + 1].  I think Mathematica gives an incorrect answer.

Comment: If you evaluate the defining Series of the Hypergeometric2F1 function you get 1/(2-b)

Comment: Enter this into your original result you get the GR expression. 1/(2-b) is not defined at b=2, but this singularity is removed by the multiplication with (2-b). So Mathematica is in principle correct, it just doesn't recognize the removal of the singularity.